# WebView, переопределить клик по гиперссылке при loadData

Tags: android, webview

Как, используя `WebView`, получить значение *href* при клике по гиперссылке?

Из-за того, что использую `webView.loadData`, переопределение `shouldOverrideUrl` не помогает - оно вообще не вызывается.

Нужно, чтобы при клике на гиперссылке (например на скрине "обрушений"), можно было получить само слово ссылки и отдельно саму ссылку в переменные. Т.е. по сути переопределить сам клик.

Подскажите - как это сделать?

В интернете и в т.ч. на *stackoverflow* все советы сводятся к `shouldOverrideUrl` - но здесь оно не работает. Или подскажите, почему этот метод не работает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример как пытался воспользоваться `shouldOverrideUrl` (для начала хотел просто вывести в лог текст ссылки\юрл)

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("TAG", url);
        return true;     
    }
});
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

Если же использовать, не `loadData`, а `loadDataWithBaseUrl` то `shouldOverrideUrl` работает:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d("TAG", url);
    return true;
}
```

выводит в лог ссылку. Но как получить слово по которому был произведён клик?

Comment: Чтобы ответить на вопрос "почему не работает" нужно больше информации. Покажите ваш WebViewClient и что вы делаете в  shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Comment: исправил 1й пост, пытался просто вызвать лог хотя бы. Даже просто Log.d("TAG", "test"); не выводилось.

Comment: а точку останова пробовали ставить?

Comment: Да, было пусто. Чуть подробнее изучив документацию на developer.android.com (не сразу понял, т.к англ прихрамывает) понял, часть своей ошибки, но появился другой вопрос. Сейчас отредактирую первый пост

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить анкор ссылки вам нужно обратится к `JavaScript`.
Приведу вам рабочий пример, будет ли он у вас работать зависит от вашей квалификации)

В первую очередь вам нужен `JavascriptInterface`

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void tagName(String html)
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", html);// <--- Анкор ссылки вы получите тут
        }
    }
```

Далее вам нужен `JavaScript` скрипт который найдет ссылку по которой вы кликнули (скрипт пройдется по DOM и выдаст вам анкор ссылки) **Скрипт нужно положить в `assets`**

```
function test(link){
    if(jsInterface === undefined){
       return;
    }
    for (var i= 0; i < document.links.length; i++){
        if(document.links[i].href == link){
            console.log(document.links[i].innerHTML);
        jsInterface.tagName(document.links[i].innerHTML)
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее вам нужно прицепить это скрипт к текущей странице, есть такая вот функция

```
private void injectScriptFile(WebView view, String scriptFile) {
        InputStream input;
        try {
            input = getAssets().open(scriptFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                    "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                    "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                    "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                    "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                    "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                    "})()");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`WebViewClient` будет выглядеть так

```
private class Client extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            injectScriptFile(view, "script.js");// script.js это скрипт который лежит в assets, скрипт инжектится когда страница полностью загрузилась
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:test('"+ url +"')"); //в момент клика по ссылке вызываем метод JS по поиску ссылок
            return true;// возвращаем true что бы не было перехода по ссылке
        }
    }
```

И в `onCreate` инжектим все это.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "jsInterface");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрался.

Comment: Да на здоровье)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
jswvWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            getBinding().etWebHttpAddress.setText(url);
         }    
});
```

Comment: "зачем танцевать с бубонами" - звучит как вопрос, а вы даёте ответ. Пожалуйста, поправте ваше сообщение стиллистически.

Comment: @VladSpirin думаю нет, не надо. Неправильный ответ не повод для тревоги, а на новый вопрос не очень похоже. Если есть сомнение, то самое быстрое кинуть ссылку в чат и спросить мнение там.